# Python build can't detect pyproject.toml file

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I keep getting the following error when I run `python -m build` in the directory I have my pyproject.toml file: `package_name does not appear to be a Python project: no pyproject.toml or setup.py`

This is how my directory looks like

```
package_root  --> Base
     setup.cfg
     MANIFEST.in
     pyproject.toml
     src/   --> Actual Module
        some_code_file.py
        some_code_file2.py
        __init__.py
```

I open a terminal and cd into the package root and run `python -m build`. The process starts to build, but after a while I get the error `package_name does not appear to be a Python project: no pyproject.toml or setup.py`

My pyproject.toml file looks like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=54",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

my setup.cfg file looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = package_name
version = 1.0
author = John Doe
author_email = johndoe@example.com
description = Test package
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = example.com
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.7
include_package_data = True
```

My MANIFEST.in file looks like:

```
exclude *.csv
```

I have created various packages using the above format -- using just setup.cfg and pyproject.toml and no setup.py -- and this is the first time I have gotten such and error. Not sure if this is relevant to it, but this time I am trying to make a package off of this github repo I have been working on. Due to certain reasons, I can't really share the repo.

Anyone have any clue what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build a package with this structure basically:

```
package_root  --> Base
     pyproject.toml
     requirements.txt
     src/   --> Actual Module
        some_code_file.py
        some_code_file2.py
        __init__.py
```

And this is the contents of my pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "ActualModuleHere"
version = "0.2.0"
authors = [
  { name="Jane Doe", email="jane.doe@example.com" },
]
description = "A package that contains utilities that data engineers use."
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/myOrgHere/myRepoNameHere"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/myOrgHere/myRepoNameHere/issues"
```

just following the documentation's example [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata).

Try just using the pyproject.toml. Does that work for you?